# Transferring IOS apps with existing admob banner

Tags: ios, admob, transfer

How to transfer IOS app to another account if admob already integrated.
Will it create problem if transferred account change existing admob unit with own unit?
Will it admob bot compares bundle identifier and behaves as fraud?

Answer (score 1):

You should delete ad units for this app before transfer as support answered.